# Remove string and all lines before string from file

Tags: python, xml, string, parsing

I have a filename with thousands of lines of data in it.
I am reading in the filename and editing it.

The following tag is about ~900 lines in or more (it varies per file):

```
<Report name="test" xmlns:cm="http://www.example.org/cm">
```

I need to remove that line and everything before it in several files.
so I need to the code to search for that tag and delete it and everything above it
it will not always be 900 lines down, it will vary; however, the tag will always be the same.

I already have the code to read in the lines and write to a file. I just need the logic behind finding that line and removing it and everything before it.

I tried reading the file in line by line and then writing to a new file once it hits on that string, but the logic is incorrect:

```
readFile = open(firstFile)
lines = readFile.readlines()
readFile.close()
w = open('test','w')
for item in lines:
    if (item == "<Report name="test" xmlns:cm="http://www.example.org/cm">"):
        w.writelines(item)
w.close()
```

In addition, the exact string will not be the same in each file. The value "test" will be different. I perhaps need to check for the tag name ""<Report name"

Comment: Read the file, line by line, and ignore everything before you reach this line. Than write everything after it to an output file.

Comment: I tried something like this, but I am not getting the result I need. Perhaps my logic is incorrect here:

readFile = open(firstFile)
 lines = readFile.readlines()
 readFile.close()
 w = open('test','w')
 for item in lines:
  if (item == "<Report name="test" xmlns:cm="http://www.domain.org/cm">"):
   w.writelines(item)
 w.close()

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code to it. Comments aren't the place to present code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a flag like `tag_found` to check when lines should be written to the output. You initially set the flag to `False`, and then change it to `True` once you've found the right tag. When the flag is `True`, you copy the line to the output file.

```
TAG = '<Report name="test" xmlns:cm="http://www.domain.org/cm">'

tag_found = False
with open('tag_input.txt') as in_file:
    with open('tag_output.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            if not tag_found:
                if line.strip() == TAG:
                    tag_found = True
            else:
                out_file.write(line)
```

PS: The `with open(filename) as in_file:` syntax is using what Python calls a "context manager"- see [here](http://python3porting.com/improving.html#coding-with-context-managers) for an overview. The short explanation of them is that they automatically take care of closing the file safely for you when the `with:` block is finished, so you don't have to remember to put in `my_file.close()` statements.

Comment: This is good. The only problem is that the exact TAG will not be the same in each file. The value "test" will be different. I perhaps need to check for the tag name "Report name" or contains?

Comment: You know your data better than anyone else on here, if you think something like `<Report name` will capture all the right lines without giving you false matches, then that's what you should match against (you might need to change the test to `if line.startswith(TAG)` or something).

Comment: Yes, there is only one line that started with <Report name. I will test this out.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I have never used the "with" statement before. If you don't mind, could you walk me through the logic here?

Comment: Check the little bit I've added- it's a way to open files without having to remember to call `.close()` on the file. The file should always be closed safely, even if something goes wrong with your program.

Comment: Ptty it deletes the stopper as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to match you line:

```
regex1 = '^<Report name=.*xmlns:cm="http://www.domain.org/cm">$'
```

Get the index of the item that matches the regex:

```
listIndex = [i for i, item in enumerate(lines) if re.search(regex, item)]
```

Slice the list:

```
listLines = lines[listIndex:]
```

And write to a file:

```
with open("filename.txt", "w") as fileOutput:
    fileOutput.write("\n".join(listLines))
```

*pseudocode*

Try something like this:

```
import re

regex1 = '^<Report name=.*xmlns:cm="http://www.domain.org/cm">$' # Variable @name
regex2 = '^<Report name=.*xmlns:cm=.*>$' # Variable @name & @xmlns:cm

with open(firstFile, "r") as fileInput:
    listLines = fileInput.readlines()

listIndex = [i for i, item in enumerate(listLines) if re.search(regex1, item)]
# listIndex = [i for i, item in enumerate(listLines) if re.search(regex2, item)] # Uncomment for variable @name & @xmlns:cm

with open("out_" + firstFile, "w") as fileOutput:
    fileOutput.write("\n".join(lines[listIndex:]))
```

Comment: It's good to explain what you expect your regexes to do, especially if you're suggesting them to people who might not necessarily be familiar with them. Yours assumes that the `name=` field will change from file to file, but that the `xmlns:cn=` field won't.

Comment: @Marius you're right, the regex would be different in that case

Comment: This is a great solution as well!